# npm run build error - malloc: error for object 0x1023e9fd0: pointer being freed was not allocated

Tags: macos, malloc, node-sass, libsass

node version: 8.10.0

npm -v: 5.6.0

system: mac

on running `npm run build`, system throws following error

> 67% building modules 2081/2181 modules 100 active
>   ...ent/completed-shipment.component.scssng(85928,0x70000312e000)
>   malloc: *** error for object 0x1023e9fd0: pointer being freed was not
>   allocated

Clearly this is because of css and probably related to variables/functions in css. But not sure where the issue lies. This was working clean 2 days earlier but started to fail now. Any known issues recently on node-sass/libsass?

Comment: Are you running 4.8.1? There is a parallelization issue being hit with webpack that should be addressed with 4.8.2

Comment: @nschonni It started to work on its own. Not sure how.